# Sorting dataframe in R in reverse order - Column name as a variable

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

I'm able to sort dataframe column in R in ascending order. However, to sort the same in descending order, what is the correct approach?

Here marketValue is the name of the variable that holds the column Name.

Ex:

```
  marketValue = 'MV_20220805'
  df[order((df[,marketValue,])),]
```

Solution as suggested.

```
df[order((df[,marketValue,]),decreasing=TRUE),]
```

Comment: [`order(...,decreasing = TRUE)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/order)

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind posting this as answer. Will accept the answer.